# How to use props in the v-bind:src directive in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple Vue app where I need to display an image in the Block component (child of App component).In the app component I use the Block component 4 times and to each component I pass a value.Based on that value the image src is chosen from an array.If I try to print

## {{ this.ImagesLeft[this.img1] }}

it works but when I use the same string in the v-bind:src of the image tag,all I see is the image icon (and the image has width and height set to 0).

Here is what I tried

Block.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>{{ this.ImagesLeft[this.img1] }}</h1>
        <img v-show="imageleft != null" v-bind:src="this.ImagesLeft[this.img1]">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    name:'SmallBlock',
    props:['title','imageleft','imageright'],
    data(){
        return{
            ImagesLeft:['../assets/pics/4.jpg','../assets/meme_pics/4.jpg'],
            img1:parseInt(this.$props.imageleft)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper-out">
    <div class="wrapper-in">
      <Block title="0" imageleft="0" imageright="0"/>
      <Block title="2" imageleft="2"/>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-in">
      <Block title="1" imageleft="1" imageright="1"/>
      <Block title="3" imageleft="3"/>
    </div>
    <Content v-show="false"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: img1 should be a computed in order to be reactive. You should import assets when using them dynamically. This depends on your setup if you could use require().

Comment: is this vuejs2 or vuejs3? You forgot to tag appropriately as mentioned in the vue.js tag

Answer (score 0):

try.  v-bind:src="require(this.ImagesLeft[this.img1])"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).